# Is this sentence correct?

Tags: перевод

нет ничего постоянного, кроме перемен.

there is nothing permanent, except change.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer "Ничто не постоянно, кроме перемен" in Russian.

Your Russian sentence is grammatically correct, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both sentences are absolutely correct and sound good.

Comment: @Artemix если еще один ответ добавиться с третьим вариантом перевода, то Вы снова исправите мой ответ? :))

Comment: Я подтверждал редактирование сделанное предыдущим пользователем, но т.к. я был с ним не вполне согласен, выбрал опцию "подтвердить и отредактировать". В результате оба варианта оказались в истории редактирования. Но вообще конечно забавно что такой короткий ответ уже три раза отредактирован.